# how to I put the input from a field on a form into a text area on the same form

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form with a name field and a text area.

When the user types in their name I want to include it in the text area along with some other pre-formatted text.

How can this be done?

jQuery?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the help. They are all great answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`keyup` handler](http://api.jquery.com/keyup) on the text input and add a `readonly="readonly"` attribute to the textarea if you want to use it for display only.

For example:

```
<input type="text">
<br>
<textarea readonly="readonly" rows="10" cols="40"></textarea>
```

And some jQuery:

```
var static_text = "Where is pancakes house?\n\n";
$('input').keyup(function() {
    $('textarea').text(static_text + $(this).val());
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Tt2gt/1/

Binding to the `keyup` event will get your `<textarea>` updating callback called every time a key is pressed in the `<input>` (including backspaces). If you use a `change` handler, the `<textarea>` won't be updated until the `<input>` loses focus and that doesn't sound like what you're after.

Comment: I did not think of the keyup and the way you explained it makes sense.  I don't need the readonly as I will allow the user to make changes to the text. Thanks very much

Comment: @chell: I wasn't sure if the `<textarea>` needed to be editable or not so I threw in the `readonly` just in case, you can drop it without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, jQuery (as well as any old JavaScript) can do that for you. What you want to do is listen for the `onchange` event. *[Click here to read more on JavaScript events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events.asp)*

In jQuery, we might have something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    $("#my_Name_Field").change( function(){

        var myText = "Some preformatted text." + 
                     "Oh, and here's the name you entered:" + $("#my_Name_Field").val();

        $("#my_Text_Field").val( myText );

    });

});
```

Where `my_Name_Field` represents the `ID` attribute of your "Name" text-field, and `my_Text_Field` represents the ID of your Text Area.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it `onchange` event or `onblur` event of your name textbox

```
$('#name-id').change(function(){

var name = $(this).val();

$('#textarea').text("this is "+ name +" . he is the user");

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/blur/

http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it with jQuery.

```
$('#namefieldID').change(function() {
  var formatedText = $("#namefieldID").val() + "any text you want";//do any formatting you want here
  $("#textareaID").val( formatedText);
});
```